# How can i look at a controller property to assign a classBinding in EmberJS Dynamically

Tags: ember.js

So far this is not working. Althrough the property should return true on my first page

Props form GWVideoApp.VideosController

```
isFirst: function() {
    return this.currentPage == 1;
}.property(),
isLast: function() {
    return this.currentPage == this.pages;
}.property(),
```

View:

```
{{#view Ember.Button target="GWVideoApp.VideosController" classBinding="GWVideoApp.VideosController.isFirst:hide" tagName="li" action="prevPage"}}Prev{{/view}}
```

When currentPage value changes the classBindings to do not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't using computed properties correctly. You need to define which property or properties on your object Ember should watch for changes on so that your computed properties are properly updated. Also, you should use Ember's universal accessors (get, getPath, set, setPath) when using properties on `Ember.Object`'s!  See below:

```
isFirst: function() {
    return Ember.get(this, 'currentPage') == 1;
}.property('currentPage'),
isLast: function() {
    return Ember.get(this, 'currentPage') == Ember.get(this, 'pages');
}.property('currentPage', 'pages'),
```

Comment: This is what i ended up with https://gist.github.com/1e5783a87da3a8a471e7 it works, is that better?